# SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier Error when compiling React project in IE11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I have a bug in my React app, where it does not work on IE11. I have tried polyfills and hoped they would handle all such errors on old browsers. The best solution would be to prompt all IE users to just download Chrome or Firefox, but theres no place for hate in the world, plus one of those users is my grandma and she's sweet, so I need to fix this.

I've added `babel-polyfill` and also tried adding it directly in the index.html `<script src-"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.23.0/polyfill.min.js"></script>.`react-app-polyfill/ie11` doesn't seem work either.

**Here's my babel config:**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false }], '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-flow'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals',
  ].filter(Boolean),
  env: {
    test: {
      presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env',{ modules: false }],
        '@babel/preset-react',
        '@babel/preset-flow',
      ],
      plugins: [
        ['emotion', { sourceMap: true, autoLabel: true }],
        '@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals',
      ],
    },
    development: {
      plugins: [['emotion', { sourceMap: true, autoLabel: true }]],
    },
  },
};
```

**Here's my Webpack config:**

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: ['whatwg-fetch', '@babel/polyfill', 'bootstrap-loader', './app/index.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[hash:6].app.js', // for code splitting. will work without but useful to set
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'assets'),
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss'],
    symlinks: false,
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve('../../node_modules/react'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime|mapbox-gl/,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'), /homelike/],
      },
      {
        test: /bootstrap-sass[\/\\]assets[\/\\]javascripts[\/\\]/,
        loader: 'imports-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV', 'APP_ENV']),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __PRODUCTION__: 'false',
    }),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new DashboardPlugin(),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
      openAnalyzer: false,
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
      awKey: env.awKey,
      tmKey: env.tmKey,
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './build',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
};
```

**Here's code from my entry point js file:**

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'object-assign-polyfill';
import 'string.prototype.startswith';
import 'string.fromcodepoint';
import '@babel/polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

...

render(
  <IconProvider>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <StripeProvider apiKey={stripeKey.pk}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
            <Router history={history}>{routes}</Router>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </StripeProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </Provider>
  </IconProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// Hot Module Replacement
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

**EDIT: index.html**
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

I get the error `SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier`

- Windows 10
- IE 11
- React 16.8.1
- webpack 4.34.0
- @babel/polyfill 7.0.0
- babel-loader 8.0.6

Comment: issue is by default the application was being rendered on IE7 that is not on only IE IE11/EDGE that support the transpiled build. So you need to mention the meta information to let browser know that the intended browser is IE11/edge. Add this in the head section of your index.html: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649831/reactjs-script1010-expected-identifier-production-build-not-running-on-ie11

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I have exactly that in my index.html `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` But it still doesn't work

Comment: I suggest you to create a new sample app and try to access it from IE 11 to check whether it is displaying properly or not. It can help to narrow down the issue like every new app has this issue or some specific code in your app causing this issue.

Comment: Are you calling dispatchEvent anywhere? I have experienced similar issues when calling dispatchEvent.

Comment: If you are using dispatchEvent in your code try using [mdn-polyfills](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdn-polyfills)

Comment: I'm not using any dispatchEvent but I tried using mdn-polyfills, still no luck